# Unable to clone repository while connected to VPN. SSL: certificate subject name does not match target host name 'github.com'

Tags: git, ssl, git-clone

I am trying to clone a git repository on a remote system connected via ssh. I need to connect to the VPN in order to ssh to the local machine of my organization.

I am trying to clone [this git repository](https://github.com/chiphuyen/stanford-tensorflow-tutorials.git) but I am getting SSL error,

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/chiphuyen/stanford-tensorflow-tutorials.git/': SSL: certificate subject name (*.<organisation-name>.com) does not match target host name 'github.com'
```

How can I clone this repository to the given remote desktop given that I can't modify system configuration?

**Basic Info:**

- The system is owned by my organization and I don't have root access on that machine (I am not `sudoer`).
- The system is Ubuntu 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [disable certificate verification](https://git.seveas.net/dealing-with-misconfigured-https-repositories.html);

```
git -c http.sslVerify=False clone \
https://github.com/chiphuyen/stanford-tensorflow-tutorials.git
```

Note that:

> Git will let you disable SSL certificate verification on a global, per host or per command invocation basis. But before you do any of this, you have to understand that this is a really bad thing: it opens you up to man-in-the-middle attacks and you should really consider all data (including passwords) sent this way to be compromised.

(Realistically speaking, for downloading some tensorflow examples it is *probably* fine.)

So it is best to do this on a per-command basis as shown above. You should *never* globally disable certificate verification;

> a grue will absolutely eat you.

At a guess, there is a good chance has nothing to do with the configuration of the system in question, or your VPN connection. I would suspect that your organization's firewall is set up to systematically intercept SSL traffic via a MITM for deep packet inspection.